# SQL Query isn't working in PHP but works in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I've been trying to add data into a table using specific queries. In PHPMyAdmin I've been using:

```
UPDATE member_food SET food_id ='5' WHERE member_id='5' AND food_type='breakfast'
```

this works, however when I try to implement it in PHP. It changed the food_id to 1.

[image]

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql_breakfast1 = "UPDATE member_food SET food_id ='$breakfast1' WHERE member_id='$id'    AND food_type='breakfast'";
if ($mysqli->query($sql_breakfast1) === TRUE) {
echo "Query: " . $sql_breakfast1;
} else {
    echo "Query: " . $sql_breakfast1 . "<br> Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Here is my result when I echo Query:

> Query: UPDATE member_food SET food_id ='8' WHERE member_id='5' AND
>   food_type='breakfast'

For confirmation that I can send data to the table, if I do it without the AND part, it works. So this works:

> Query: UPDATE member_food SET food_id ='8' WHERE member_id='5'

How do I debug this situation? What's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: What's the Error-Message?

Comment: dump `$breakfast1` and see what is in it?

Comment: @92_egdeH I posted about. There is no Error. It thinks it's posted the correct value instead it changes food_id to 1.

Comment: @sgt look above at the result of the echo'd query.

Comment: @BradlySpicer we are missing vital parts of your code. If you say this is all then nothing would work because $breakfast1 has no value. Show us where you assign value to $breakfast1

Comment: @Shaeldon $breakfast1 is taken from a form in a previous page... it's shown in the "Query: UPDATE member_food SET food_id='8' WHERE member_id='5' AND food_type='breakfast'" ...

Comment: @sgt I checked the database...

Comment: @BradlySpicer then show us the form

Comment: @Shaeldon why do you need to see the form? $sql_breakfast1 is defined above and then I'm showing the echo'd query which PROVES it's being given a value of 8 in the food_id and a member_id of 5...

Comment: @BradlySpicer Looks to me like it's a variable interpolation problem. Don't place variables straight into the string. Concatenate them into it like this: `"UPDATE member_food SET food_id ='".$breakfast1."'...`

Comment: @Alternatex I'l try that when I get back to using my variables. I've just tried a manual SQL Query like so: "UPDATE member_food SET food_id='12' WHERE member_id='5' AND food_type='breakfast'";

The food_id still returns as 1... the moment I move the AND part, it works without that extra part

Comment: @Alternatex If I use this it works:
`UPDATE member_food SET food_id=12 WHERE member_id=4 AND food_type="breakfast"` However, when it's food_id instead of food_type it breaks.

Comment: @BradlySpicer "when it's food_id instead of food_type it breaks". What exactly do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use php variable directly in the query. **Prepare and Bind variables**.

Also see the server error log or  set error info show in the development mode so you will see any notices or errors directly in the browser.

Update

Do not use string in bind param.

Try Like this:

```
$sql_breakfast1 = "UPDATE member_food SET food_id =? WHERE member_id=?  AND food_type=?";
stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_breakfast1);


if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die($mysqli->error);
}
$sis = 'sis';
$strBreakFast = 'breakfast';
$rc = $stmt->bind_param($sis, $breakfast1, $id, $strBreakFast);

if ( false===$rc ) {
  die($stmt->error);
}

$rc = $stmt->execute();

if ( false===$rc ) {
  die($stmt->error);
}

$stmt->close()
```

Comment: > Okay, I just clicked it's String Integer String... I am however getting this error: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 4 by reference.

Here is my whole page, incase I'm missing something: http://pastebin.com/DacKi9yh

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$sql_breakfast1 = "UPDATE member_food SET food_id ="'.$breakfast1.'" WHERE member_id="'.$id.'" AND food_type="'breakfast'"";
```

Play with the single quotes, try removing them on each of the variables and on `breakfast` one by one.